# Equivalence between standard optimization problem and Langragian form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given a problem:
$$\min_x f(x)$$
subject to
$$g(x) \le C$$

In general, when it is equivalent to the problem 
$$\min_x f(x) + \lambda g(x)$$
for certain $\lambda$?

Here my equivalence means : the solution for the latter given a $\lambda$ must be the solution of the former for some $C$, though the mapping between $\lambda$ and $C$ can not be easily found. And vice versa.

Clearly, for convex problem where $g$ and $f$ are convex functions, this is always true due to the strong duality. But in general, is it true? For example, we $f$ is convex but $g$ is not (or vice versa), do we still have the equivalence? Seems like it is easy to claim that the solution set of the second problem (solutions for $\lambda \in [0, \infty)$) must be contained in the solution set of the first problem (solutions for $C \in [0, \infty)$). How about the reverse?

Comment: In fact it is not necessarily "equivalent" even for convex functions (depending on your def of "equivalent").  Consider $f(x)=-x$, $g(x)=x - \sqrt{2}$.  Minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x) \leq 0$ gives the only solution $x^*=\sqrt{2}$.  But for $\lambda=1$ (the only multiplier that yields zero duality gap), minimizing $f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to "minimizing" the function $0$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So all real numbers $x$ are minimizers.  So this new problem  provides no help in finding the specific point $x^*=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: There are lots of books on this topic.  I wrote some notes related to this, focusing on optimization for networks:  Theorem II.2 on page 7 seems to be exactly what you are asking about. http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/network-optimization-notes.pdf

Comment: I'm with @Michael, and not just because he shares my first name. These problems are *not* equivalent. Equivalence means that you can readily obtain the solution to problem A given a solution to problem B, _and vice versa_. You can almost never know in advance which value of $\lambda$ is required to make the second problem produce the same value as the first. Hence this pair of problems fails the equivalence test.

Comment: @ltx5151 : You also ask for examples of when strong duality fails.  Can you answer your own question below? (you are allowed to do that)  You can experiment with simple functions for $f$ and $g$, such as $x^2$, $-x^2$,$x-1/2$, $-x-1/2$, and simple intervals such as $x \in [0,1]$ or $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  "Most" nonconvex examples will directly lead you to a nonzero duality gap:  So you do not have to do much work, and you will learn more by constructing your own examples.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. I revise the description of a bit. I guess my original description is a bit misleading. I agree that from solving one problem leads to the solution of the other problem is the usual meaning of "equivalence". But that is not exactly I mean. So I should more clearly state my "equivalence" as the solution of the latter problem (Lagrangian form) with a given $\lambda$ must be a solution of the former problem (standard form) for some $C$ even though we make not find the mapping between $\lambda$ and $C$.